# How to make a @Binding variable refresh the view

Tags: swiftui

As far as I understand, if I need to update the view model from inside a view, I need to make it a binding variable.

The model.

```
enum Options: Int, Identifiable, Equatable, CaseIterable {
    case option1 = 1
    case option2 = 2
    case option3 = 3
    case option4 = 4
    
    var id: String { "\(self.rawValue)" }
}

class TestViewModel:  ObservableObject {
    var selectedOption = Options.option1
    ...
}
```

The view.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @Binding var viewModel: TestViewModel
    @State var selectedOption = Options.option1

    var body: some View {
        
        Picker("Option 1", selection: $viewModel.selectedOption) {
            ForEach(Options.allCases, id: \.id) { value in
                Text(value.id)
                    .tag(value)
            }
        }
        Text("Selected Option: \(viewModel.selectedOption.rawValue)")
        
        Picker("Option 2", selection: $selectedOption) {
            ForEach(Options.allCases, id: \.id) { value in
                Text(value.id)
                    .tag(value)
            }
        }
        Text("Selected Option: \(selectedOption.rawValue)")
    }
        
}
```

- Selecting a value in the first picket, the view doesn't refresh.
- Selecting a value in the second picker, the view refreshes (as expected)

How can I make the view refresh using @Binding which is required to update the model?

I come up with this solution which works but it doesn't look good to me.

```
...
 let b = Binding<Options>(
            get: {
                viewModel.selectedOption
            },
            set: {
                viewModel.selectedOption = $0
                selectedOption = $0 // << this forces the view to refresh
            }
        )

 Picker("Speed 1", selection: b) {
            ForEach(Options.allCases, id: \.id) { value in
                Text(value.id)
                    .tag(value)
            }
        }
...
```

Comment: Binding does not refresh a view, view is refreshed by changed state, to which binding has bound, but not always - only when body of the view depends on that state.

Answer (score 2):

The `ObservableObject` works in pair with `ObservedObject` wrapper. In such case view model becomes source of truth for a view. So...

1. make property published

```
class TestViewModel:  ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedOption = Options.option1     // << here !!
    ...
}
```

2. make view model wrapped by ObservedObject

```
struct TestView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: TestViewModel
```

3. bind picker directly to view model

```
 Picker("Speed 1", selection: $viewModel.selectedOption) {
            ForEach(Options.allCases, id: \.id) { value in
                Text(value.id)
                    .tag(value)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have a valid reason to use `ObservableObject` here but you can easily achieve the same results by using a `struct` and `State` variable:

```
struct TestViewModel {

    var selectedOption = Options.option1
}

struct TestView: View {

    @State var viewModel: TestViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Picker("Option 1", selection: $viewModel.selectedOption) {
            ForEach(Options.allCases, id: \.id) { value in
                Text(value.id)
                    .tag(value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```